# How to create some methods(ex: insertAtIndex()) for custom linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am new to the concept of Linked list, and I am having a lot of trouble building this custom linked list for the first time.

I have two classes: `CellPhone` and `CellList`.

In `CellPhone`, I have 4 attributes: serialNum(long), brand(String), year(int), and price(double).

In `CellList`, I have:

- an inner class called `CellNode`, which has two attributes: phone(CellPhone), and next(CellNode)
- and two attributes head(CellNode) and size(int)

This is from my CellList class:

```
private CellNode head; // point first node in this list object
private int size; // current size of the list(how many nodes in the list)

public CellList() {
    head = null;
    size = 0;
}
public CellList(CellList c) { // is this a correct deep copying?
    head = new CellNode(c.head);
    size = c.getSize();
}

public int getSize() {
    return size;
}

public void addToStart(CellPhone c) {
    head = new CellNode(c, null); //head.getPhone() = c, head.getNextNode() = null.
    size++;
}
```

I am not even sure if that `addToStart` method is correctly done, and now I need to add methods like `insertAt(/deleteFrom)Index(CellPhone c, int index)`. I've done till here:

```
public void insertAtIndex(CellPhone c, int index) { //index is invalid when it's not 0<index<size-1
    if(index<0 || index>size-1) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("index is invalid! System terminated.");
    }
```

but I can't fully understand how this `Node` thing works, so I am stuck.

---

Here is the full code:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class CellList {

    class CellNode {
        private CellPhone phone;
        private CellNode next;
        public CellNode() {
            phone = null;
            next = null;
        }
        public CellNode(CellPhone c, CellNode n) {
            phone = c;
            next = n;
        }
        public CellNode(CellNode c) {
            this(c.getPhone(), c.getNextNode());
        }

        public CellNode clone() {
            CellNode c = new CellNode(phone, next);
            return c;
        }

        public CellPhone getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }
        public CellNode getNextNode() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setPhone(CellPhone c) {
            phone = c;
        }
        public void setNextNode(CellNode n) {
            next = n;
        }
    }

    private CellNode head; // point first node in this list object
    private int size; // current size of the list(how many nodes in list)

    public CellList() {
        head = null;
        size = 0;
    }
    public CellList(CellList c) {
        head = new CellNode(c.head);
        size = c.getSize();
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void addToStart(CellPhone c) {
        head = new CellNode(c, null); //head.getPhone() = c, head.getNextNode() = null.
        size++;
    }

    public void insertAtIndex(CellPhone c, int index) { //index is invalid when it's not 0<index<size-1
        if(index<0 || index>size-1) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("index is invalid! System terminated.");
        }

    }

    public void showContents() {
        while(head.getNextNode() != null) {
            System.out.println(head.getPhone()+"---->");
            head = head.getNextNode();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a node at an index x you have to,
go to the node at index x-1, store the next value of node x-1 in a temp variable, put the node you want to insert in next property of x-1 node, and put the value in the temp variable in the next property of the node you want to insert.